# Getting Error Passing values from Controller Laravel to Ajax Jquery GET Json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I´m using Laravel 5.4 for Backend server

This is my Backend side of Controller:

```
$locations = Neighborhood::where('House_id', $id)->get();

    $json =  json_encode($locations);

      return response()->json($json);
```

This is my Ajax Jquery Script:

```
  $(document).ready(function (){
      var map = new GMaps({
        div: '#mymap',
        lat: 32.651287,
        lng: -16.885297,
        zoom:15
      });
    $.ajax({
            url:"api/maps/house/1",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            crossDomain: "true",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.type == false) {
                    alert("Error occured:" + result.data);
                    return false;
                }
                $.each(data,function(index,obj){

                    alert(obj.name);

          });
      },
      error: function(result){
           alert(result);
      }

      });
    });
```

I´m getting error result alert with `Obj Obj`

This is my JSON Strucutre:

```
"[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Dolce Vita\",\"House_id\":1,\"lat\":\"32.647471\",\"lng\":\"-16.914049\"}]"
```

Comment: RTFM https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses#json-responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line not required `$json =  json_encode($locations);`. Remove that line from your code. because that is nor required. `return response()->json($locations);` this line will send response in json format.

```
$locations = Neighborhood::where('House_id', $id)->get();
return response()->json($locations);
```

Comment: do you want to get single record? then use `first()` instead of `get()` method

Comment: I dont want the first i want all record to pass the values to json

Answer (score 2):

When you do `response()->json`, response will converted to json. SO you do not need to do `json_encode` before it

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses

So change your controoler to

```
$locations = Neighborhood::where('House_id', $id)->get();
return response()->json($locations);
```